# Scrapy - NameError: global name 'base_search_url' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, local-variables

I am trying to call a local variable from inside a Scrapy spider class but then I got `NameError: global name 'base_search_url' is not defined`.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mine"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]

    base_url = "https://www.example.com"

    start_date = "2011-01-01"

    today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    base_search_url = 'https://www.example.com/?city={}&startDate={}&endDate={}&page=1',

    city_codes = ['on', 'bc', 'ab']

    start_urls = (base_search_url.format(city_code, start_date, today) for city_code in city_codes)
```

I tried to use `self.base_search_url` instead but there is no use. Does anyone know how to solve it?

FYI, I use Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I end up solving it by using `__init__()` function.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.start_urls = (self.base_search_url.format(city_code, self.start_date, self.today) for city_code in self.city_codes)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_urls):

> start_urls: a list of URLs where the Spider will begin to crawl from.
>   The first pages downloaded will be those listed here. The subsequent
>   URLs will be generated successively from data contained in the start
>   URLs.

Start urls is a **list**

Solve it by set in **init** method:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.start_urls=[]
    self.start_urls.append( (base_search_url.format(city_code, start_date,     today) for city_code in city_codes) )
```

Or in the class declaration (as you show in your question):

```
start_urls=[]
start_urls.append( (base_search_url.format(city_code, start_date,     today) for city_code in city_codes) )
```

**Note**

Make sure you add correct urls starting by `http://` or `https://`.

Answer (score 0):

There are only four ranges in Python: `LEGB`, because the local scope of the `class` definition and the local extent of the `list derivation` are not nested functions, so they do not form the Enclosing scope.Therefore, they are two separate local scopes that cannot be accessed from each other.

3 solutions:

```
 1. global base_search_url
 2. def __init__(self) ...
 3. start_urls = ('https://www.example.com/?city={}&startDate={}&endDate={}&page=1'.format ... )
```